# How can one meaningfully say that one field generates the other in an EM-wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, education, maxwell-equations

This is a follow up question to: [Do the electric and magnetic components of an electromagnetic wave really generate each other?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/181277/do-the-electric-and-magnetic-components-of-an-electromagnetic-wave-really-genera)

Clearly there are nuances of how one states the "mutual induction" explanation for EM-waves. My question is, of how strong can the statement in this direction be if one insists on that there should be a mathematical proof for it starting from Maxwell's equations. Nevertheless the statement should be simple enough to serve as (correct  but) "popularized" view on the EM-field and it should be close to what is often said about EM-waves and mutual generation of the field in undergraduate and high school physics courses.

If one says that one field generates the other, one should distinguish between a causal relation and a logical one (assuming Maxwell's theory).

Let's start with the second (I guess weaker) interpretation:

From Maxwell's equations in vacuum:

$$ \nabla \times \mathbf{E} = - \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} $$
$$ \nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}\,.$$

one can see that if one field is changing with time, logically necessary (assuming the validity of Maxwell's equations) there must also be the other field (not necessary both in the same point, but somewhere in space, i.e. it can not be identically zero since this would imply that the curl is zero and thus also the time derivative of the other field).

This seems to be a very weak interpretation of the mutual generation thing. One guess to make the statement stronger may be not to talk about existence but say something like: If one field $\mathbf{E}$ is changing with time, there must be a $\mathbf{B}$-field which is also changing with time (and vice versa).

This seems to be wrong, take for example

$$
\mathbf{E} = 2\hat{\mathbf{z}}t
$$

and

$$
\mathbf{B} = y \hat{\mathbf{x}} - x \hat{\mathbf{y}}
$$

This satisfies the Maxwell equations in vacuum. $\mathbf{E}$ is changing with time, but $\mathbf{B}$ is not. So the stronger statement seems to be wrong.

Another idea to make is stronger is to say that if the time derivative of one field is high, the value of the other field is high. This is clearly wrong if one talks about the same point in space, as an in phase EM-wave shows.

Clearly one can rephrase the Maxwell equation, but speaking directly about the curl is not what I am looking for since it should be something which you can express in simple words...

Up to now this is all logically not causally. How can one interpret the statement in a causal way such that it is correct? Since electric and magnetic fields are "just" different components (in a fixed reference system) of the electromagnetic field tensor I guess that there will be no correct causal statement at all, but I am not sure.

Comment: Note that the proper "causal" formuation of Maxwell's equations are [Jefimenko's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko's_equations), where one now cannot talk about one field generating the other.

Comment: *"This seems to be a very weak interpretation of the mutual generation thing"*: why is it weak?

Comment: The electromagnetic field is one field, not two. You are simply looking at an old way of writing the equations of motion for its components. If you don't like the old way, there are plenty of newer books that use a tensorial formulation that unifies the notation, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor

Comment: @CuriousOne I don't really see how your comment relates to my question.

Comment: Your question is not about physics but about notation. The electromagnetic field is one field. It's only our notation that picks it apart into E and B components.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco: As indicated in my question there are possible (but maybe wrong) stronger interpretations, so the first interpretation is the weakest one occuring in my question and the weakest one I know.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Often one hears explanations of electromagnetic waves on high school or undergraduate level, where someone says something like: "The idea is that the changing magnetic field induces a changing electric field and the other way around."  This is stronger (but wrong as stated in my question). And you get the feeling that this should "explain" the occurence of the electromagnetic wave. So I expect there is some stronger (but correct) interpretation of this statement than my first interpretation in my questioni.

Comment: @CuriousOne No this **is** a physical question in the realm of this formalism. If you want a covariant notation you may ask the same question about the components of $F_{\mu\nu}$ given a fixed reference system, so if you want: "The question is notation covariant" :-).

Comment: @Julia I understand the meaning of the question but I don't see how one interpretation may be weaker than the other: it is just what it is, namely non-zero electric (magnetic) fields result in non-zero magnetic (electric) curls. The point of electromagnetism is however *not* that one field generates the other, rather that one field *is exactly* the other if you change reference frame.

Comment: @Julia: We have never required causality between anything and itself. We only require causality between different entities. E and B fields are not different entities.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Weaker in  logical sense. Just like: "Every polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ of degree $n > 0$ has at least one root" is (true but) weaker than "Every polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ of degree $n  > 0$ has exactly $n$ roots".

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Ok, that answers the second part of my question about the causal part. So you would agree that there is no causal relation just as I wrote it above. What do you mean about the logical part?

Comment: @Julia I believe your confusion comes from the fact that you are trying to interpret something when there's nothing really to interpret "in the logical sense", as you phrased. It is not generally true that "electric fields generate magnetic fields and viceversa"; what is true is that non-zero curls are left hand sides of non-vanishing electric (magnetic) fields (which in turn corresponds to the relativity statement if you change reference frames for all the equations to be preserved).

Comment: @Julia: Electric field is not formed by changing magnetic field; electric field and magnetic field exist simultaneously; how can there be any causal relation between them? Both are produced by changing current at retarded time. See, [Jefimenko's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations#Discussion). Also, check this brilliant paper by the same author:  http://www.kathodos.com/causalityelectromagnetic.pdf .

Comment: If you vote to close, please comment why and how to improve the question.

Comment: Saying "X causes Y" in physics is a really tricky thing. We have equations relating things to other things; who is to say the left hand side causes the right hand side, or vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

> How can one meaningfully say that one field generates the other in an EM-wave?

You can't because they don't. The electromagnetic wave is an *electromagnetic* field variation. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_field#Dynamics) where you can read this: *"Over time, it was realized that the electric and magnetic fields are better thought of as two parts of a greater whole — the electromagnetic field".*

Or see section 11.10 of Jackson's [Classical Electrodynamics](https://archive.org/stream/ClassicalElectrodynamics/Jackson-ClassicalElectrodynamics#page/n397/mode/2up) where he says this: *"one should properly speak of the electromagnetic field F<sub>μν</sub> rather than E or B separately"*.

Or see Jefimenko [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations#Discussion): *"...neither Maxwell's equations nor their solutions indicate an existence of causal links between electric and magnetic fields. Therefore, we must conclude that an electromagnetic field is a dual entity always having an electric and a magnetic component simultaneously created by their common sources: time-variable electric charges and currents".*

It's a popscience myth that an E wave generates a B wave which generates an E wave. One of those ["lies to children"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children) that ends up being widely believed, even by professional physicists.

> Clearly there are nuances of how one states the "mutual induction" explanation for EM-waves.

I'm afraid there's no nuance at all Julia. The "mutual induction" explanation  is wrong. E and B are in phase because [they're space and time derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Derivation_from_electromagnetic_theory). See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/223989/76162) where I used a canoe analogy.

> My question is, of how strong can the statement in this direction be if one insists on that there should be a mathematical proof for it starting from Maxwell's equations. Nevertheless the statement should be simple enough to serve as (correct  but) "popularized" view on the EM-field and it should be close to what is often said about EM-waves and mutual generation of the field in undergraduate and high school physics courses.

There is no mathematical proof. The equals sign in $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = - \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} $ and in $\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}\ $ does not indicate cause. Instead you should read it as "is another aspect of". Or simply "is".

> If one says that one field generates the other, one should distinguish between a causal relation and a logical one (assuming Maxwell's theory).

Maxwell unified electricity and magnetism to give us the electromagnetic field. But here we are 150 years later and people still will talk about E and B as if they're two totally different things. Tut.

> Let's start with the second (I guess weaker) interpretation: From Maxwell's equations in vacuum: $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = - \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} $ [and] $\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}\ $ one can see that if one field is changing with time, logically necessary (assuming the validity of Maxwell's equations) there must also be the other field (not necessary both in the same point, but somewhere in space, i.e. it can not be identically zero since this would imply that the curl is zero and thus also the time derivative of the other field).

There aren't really two different fields, there's one field, and two derivatives. Spatial and time.

> This seems to be a very weak interpretation of the mutual generation thing.

Agreed. When you look into it it just doesn't stand up.

> One guess to make the statement stronger may be not to talk about existence but say something like: If one field $\mathbf{E}$ is changing with time, there must be a $\mathbf{B}$-field which is also changing with time (and vice versa).

That's not quite right because there's only one field there. Electromagnetic field interactions typically result in linear and/or rotational force. When we only see linear force we typically talk of an E field, when we only see rotational motion we typically talk of a B field, but these result from F<sub>μν</sub> field interactions.

> This seems to be wrong...

It is.

> Up to now this is all logically not causally. How can one interpret the statement in a causal way such that it is correct?

You can't, because it isn't.

> Since electric and magnetic fields are "just" different components (in a fixed reference system) of the electromagnetic field tensor I guess that there will be no correct causal statement at all, but I am not sure.

Shrug. There is no correct causal statement at all.

Answer (score 1):

A changing electric field does generate a magnetic field, ( hence  electromagnets) and a changing magnetic field generates an electric field.  The solution for radiated energy is given in terms of electric and magnetic fields in a given reference frame.

This animation is instructive for radiation:

[image]

> [Electromagnetic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) can be imagined as a self-propagating transverse oscillating wave of electric and magnetic fields. This 3D animation shows a plane linearly polarized wave propagating from left to right. **Note that the electric and magnetic fields in such a wave are in-phase with each other, reaching minima and maxima together**

Bold mine.

Here electric and magnetic fields increase and decrease together, how can one be creating the other? The wave solution of the combined  maxwell equations differs from the solutions for stand alone  ones for electric and magnetic fields.

Aside:

At a specific $(x,y,z)$ at time $t$ both electric and magnetic fields are zero, nevertheless the light beam carries energy :

\begin{align}S&= \frac{1}{c\mu_0} E_m^2 \;\overline{\sin^2(kx-\omega t)}\\&= \frac{1}{c\mu_0}\frac{E_m^2}{2}\;.\end{align}

> [The rate of energy transport](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/waves/emwv.html)t S is perpendicular to both E and B and in the direction of propagation of the wave.(A condition of the wave solution for a plane wave is Bm = Em/c )

It always bothered me that zero $E$ and $B\;,$ where is the energy at that point? One can sympathize with the need for a luminiferous ether, which was disposed of experimentally. The averaging seemed to gloss over  that zero.

But the particulate nature of light, photons, in some sense compensates for the non existent ether. The classical beam emerges from a confluence of photons which individually carry the energy  $h\nu.$ The electromagnetic  wave's $E$ and $B$ are built up by zillions of photons which are excitations on the photon field and [add up in the necessary way](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) to produce the classical beam.

Comment: Hi! Please check the equation. I've altered it using mathjax.

Comment: @anna v Thanks for your post, but sorry, I don't see how this answers my question, you just rephrase the statement, my question is about, and then recall some other (well known) facts about EM-waves, but I don't see the relation to my question.

Comment: It answers it in the negative. that for em waves  changing electric fields  do not generate magnetic fields  and vice verso, as is evident in this particular solution.

Comment: @Anna, thanks for your edit. This gives an argument, that there is no causal relation.

Comment: When E and B are zero the energy is in the potential. E is the spatial derivative of it, B is the time derivative. It's like you go over a (troughless) wave in a canoe. The slope of your canoe is E and the change of slope is B. At the top of the wave your canoe is horizontal and momentarily still, so E and B are zero. But +1 for no causal relation.

Comment: Anna try for photons this: $$\text{electric field}: E = E_m\sin(kx - \omega t) \\\\\\\ \text{magnetic field}: B = B_m \cos(kx - \omega t) $$ The energy stays constant in all points of the photons movement. Does this is a possible solution in Maxwells equations? If not, how the equations have to be rewrite?

Comment: For radio waves, this is another case. The source (wave generator) produces modulated radiation and of course, at the moments, the generator does not give power periodically, the radio wave has zero intensity too. In this traveling points the electric and the magnetic field components are both zero. But this has nothing to do with the individual photons, emitted from the antenna rod.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler photons are the underlying quantum mechanical layer of the classical beam.. Photons first in confluence and then classical beams is what mainstream electromagnetic theory has established and modeled very successfully

Comment: @HolgerFiedler energy is not easily defined within the classical EM, it is only averages over wavelengths , the Poynting vector, that have connection with energy in other forms. This is seen in the equation in my answer.